# Using Xpath to store value in Gatling

Tags: xml, scala, xpath, scala-gatling

I'm trying to store the value of a uuid "EnquiryId" from an XML response. I believe the standard approach is to use xpath but I'm not using it correctly and receiving "java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: enquiryId"

Response Example:

```
<created_enquiry xmlns="http://www.test.com/energy-rest-enquiry.xsd">
    <enquiry_id id="1705230d-a64d-f075-e477-b11c3dabfa9c" link="value"/>
</created_enquiry>
```

Code example:

```
http("REST  Users Post Submit Enquiry")
  .post("/rest/enquiry/enquiry")
  .headers(headersREST)
  .body(ELFileBody("RestSubmitEnquiry.xml"))
  .check(status.is(201))
  .check(xpath("/*/enquiry_id/@id").saveAs("enquiryId"))
```

Thanks